# Use multiple queries in blade view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Pretty new to Laravel and trying to figure out the ins and outs.
If I write one main query that selects everything in my table, can I write individual queries when selecting columns and rows from the table.

Example:

Main Query:

```
public function allTickets(){
$tickets = DB::table('tickets')->get();
return view('admin.index',compact('tickets'));
```

In my view:

```
//THIS WORKS. It gives me a count of all open and closed tickets
{{$tickets->where('status', '=', 'OPEN')->Count()}}
{{$tickets->where('status', '=', 'CLOSED')->Count()}}
```

However this does not work...

> Error: Call to a member function where() on string (View: ...

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ts)
{{$ts->subject->where('status', '=', 'OPEN')}}
@endforeach

@foreach ($tickets as $ts)
{{$ts->subject->where('status', '=', 'CLOSED')}}
@endforeach
```

Is there a way to use that ONE main query and show all the subjects of the tickets that are open and closed, or will I need to write multiple queries in my controller to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this with simple solution.
first write one and then another one with if statement

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ts)
  @if($ts->status == 'OPEN')
     {{$ts->subject}}
  @endif
@endforeach

@foreach ($tickets as $ts)
  @if($ts->status == 'CLOSED')
    {{ $ts->subject }}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Totally overlooked that. That works perfectly.

Comment: Also figured out this works. `@foreach ($tickets->sortBy('created_at')->where('status', '=', 'OPEN')->take(1) as $ts)` Outputs the first ticket only.